# how to get a full news article from a website with scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm still learning how to do web scraping, and I'm trying to scrape a website by getting all the articles from an index page and then grab their information, and also the full text.
With the code below, I could get all the information I need – date, time, category, title — except for the full article.

`text':  news.css('p.categoryArticle__excerpt::text').get()` did not capture all the text.

Here is the code I wrote so far:

```
import scrapy

class CoalNewsFromOilPrice(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'coalnews'
    start_urls = ['https://oilprice.com/Energy/Coal/']

    def parse(self, response):
        for news in response.css('div.categoryArticle__content'):
            yield {
                'datetime': news.css('p.categoryArticle__meta::text').get(),
                'category': news.xpath('//h1[@class="categoryHeading"]/text()').extract()[0].replace('/', '').replace(' ',''),
                'title': news.css('h2.categoryArticle__title::text').get(),
                'text':  news.css('p.categoryArticle__excerpt::text').get(),
            }
        next_page = response.css('a.num').attrib['href']
        if next_page is not None:
            yield response.follow(next_page, callback = self.parse)
```

and here the elements I need. When I open the html url, it shows the full text. But I still did not get how should I get it. I am thinking to extract the html url, but I dont know how.

```
<div class="categoryArticle__content">
    
       <a href="https://oilprice.com/Energy/Coal/Russias-Coal-Exports-Are-On-The-Rise-As-EU-Ban-Looms.html">
          <h2 class="categoryArticle__title">Russia’s Coal Exports Are On The Rise As EU Ban Looms</h2>
       </a>
       <p class="categoryArticle__meta">Jul 06, 2022 at 09:41 | Tsvetana Paraskova</p>
       <p class="categoryArticle__excerpt"></p>
        Russian seaborne coal exports are estimated to have increased since Putin’s 
        invasion of Ukraine and the EU announcement it was banning Russian coal imports 
        from August.&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

                        </div>
```

What should I do to get the full text of the articles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now your code is working fine with pulling full text along with pagination in start_urls. Actually, I go to the details page and from the details page, I grab all the required data items using xpath expression.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

class CoalNewsFromOilPrice(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'coalnews'
    start_urls = ['https://oilprice.com/Energy/Coal/Page-'+str(x)+'.html' for x in range(1,18)]

    def parse(self, response):
        for link in response.xpath('//*[@class="categoryArticle__content"]/a/@href'):
            yield scrapy.Request(
                url=link.get(),
                callback=self.parse_item
            )

    def parse_item(self, response):
        yield {
            'datetime': response.xpath('//*[@class="article_byline"]/text()[2]').get(),
            'category': response.xpath('(//*[@itemprop="name"])[3]/text()').get(),
            'title': response.xpath('//*[@class="singleArticle__content"]/h1/text()').get(),
            'text':''.join([x.get().strip() for x in response.xpath('//*[@id="article-content"]//p//text()')])
            }
       


if __name__ == '__main__':
    process = CrawlerProcess()
    process.crawl(CoalNewsFromOilPrice)
    process.start()
```

Answer (score 0):

Success in web scraping is all about understanding the HTML structure of the page you're targeting, and writing the correct selectors.

In exactly the same way as you, a human, would navigate through the links and view the content, your code should navigate to each link on the start URL and then look for the right element to get.

It looks like there is a div with the id of `#article-content` on each article that should get you the full text.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).